# How to check if a string contains a specific text

Tags: php

```
<?php
$a = '';

if($a exist 'some text')
    echo 'text';
?>
```

Suppose I have the code above, how to write the statement `if($a exist 'some text')`?

Comment: You mean this: `if($a == 'some text')` . Here some more info over operators: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: If the size of the string is greater than 0 , then the string has some text in it.

Comment: If you are checking the string if it has any text then this should work `if(strlen($a) > 0) echo 'text';` or if your concern is to check for specific word the follow the @Dai answer.

Answer (score 210, accepted):

Use the `strpos` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

```
$haystack = "foo bar baz";
$needle   = "bar";

if( strpos( $haystack, $needle ) !== false) {
    echo "\"bar\" exists in the haystack variable";
}
```

In your case:

```
if( strpos( $a, 'some text' ) !== false ) echo 'text';
```

Note that my use of the `!==` operator (instead of `!= false` or `== true` or even just `if( strpos( ... ) ) {`) is because of the ["truthy"/"falsy"](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) nature of PHP's handling of the return value of `strpos`.

As of PHP 8.0.0 you can now use [str_contains](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-contains.php)

```
<?php
    if (str_contains('abc', '')) {
        echo "Checking the existence of the empty string will always 
        return true";
    }
```

Comment: Won't a non-match return 0?

Comment: `false >= 0`. You have to write `!== false`, as `0 == false`.

Comment: @Blender sorry, you're right. I was thinking of the .NET `String.IndexOf` which returns `-1` in event of a non-match. I've corrected my answer.

Comment: And `stripos()` for **insensitive** string comparison ...

Comment: It's same:

if(! strpos( $haystack, $needle ) == false) {
    echo "\"bar\" exists in the haystack variable";
}

more simple and objective...

Comment: @PadronizaçãoSA The `!` operator will affect the falsiness of the return value from `strpos` which means `===` won't work the way it's intended.

Comment: Test it on PHP 7.

Comment: @Leeish : If the text being searched within the string starts at position 0, its matches and so will return 0. (I know old post but might interest someone reaching this post).

Comment: As docs state:  "  Return Value:  Returns the position of the first occurrence of a string inside another string, or FALSE if the string is not found. Note: String positions start at 0, and not 1."

Answer (score 18):

Empty strings are falsey, so you can just write:

```
if ($a) {
    echo 'text';
}
```

Although if you're asking if a particular substring exists in that string, you can use `strpos()` to do that:

```
if (strpos($a, 'some text') !== false) {
    echo 'text';
}
```

Comment: Also if you want it to find "Some Text", "SOME TEXT", etc. use `stripos` (which is case insensitive)

Answer (score 8):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php  I think you are wondiner if 'some text' exists in the string right?

```
if(strpos( $a , 'some text' ) !== false)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need to know if a word exists in a string you can use this. As it is not clear from your question if you just want to know if the variable is a string or not. Where 'word' is the word you are searching in the string.

```
if (strpos($a,'word') !== false) {
echo 'true';
}
```

or use the is_string method. Whichs returns true or false on the given variable.

```
<?php
$a = '';
is_string($a);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `==` [comparison operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) to check if the variable is equal to the text:

```
if( $a == 'some text') {
    ...
```

You can also use `strpos` function to return the first occurrence of a string:

```
<?php
$mystring = 'abc';
$findme   = 'a';
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);

// Note our use of ===.  Simply == would not work as expected
// because the position of 'a' was the 0th (first) character.
if ($pos === false) {
    echo "The string '$findme' was not found in the string '$mystring'";
} else {
    echo "The string '$findme' was found in the string '$mystring'";
    echo " and exists at position $pos";
}
```

[See documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `strpos()` or `stripos()` to check if the string contain the given needle. It will return the position where it was found, otherwise will return FALSE.

Use the operators `===` or `!==  to differ FALSE from 0 in PHP.