# error while using custom html property tags

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make every HTML element in my project clickable. When it is clicked, it should take me to another webpage (other.html)
my JS:

```
let objs = document.querySelectorAll( 'body *' );
console.log(objs)
Array.from(objs).map(x => {
if (x.hasAttribute('loc') && x.hasAttribute('trig')){
let loc = x.getAttribute('loc')
let trig = x.getAttribute('trig')
let functionAtLast = function() {location.href = loc}
x.addEventListener(trig, functionAtLast)

}
})
```

my HTML:

```
<b loc = 'other.html' trig = 'click'>hi</b>
```

When I click on the bold text, nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: "I am trying to make every HTML element in my project clickable" - **why**? That sounds like a bad idea because not every HTML element is interactable (e.g. `<script>` and `<noscript>`, `<style>`, etc)

Comment: Custom attributes should be written with `data-`. See [Using data attributes](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes). Does nothing happen or do you receive an error? If the latter, what is the error?

Comment: `map` is an FP-style function that returns a new array, it is not equivalent to `forEach`.

Comment: You should change your selector to `body *[log][trig]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`map` should not be used to *mutate* array elements - nor is it *intended* to be used to iterate over an array. For that you should use `for( of )` (don't use the `.forEach` method either).

- You should use HTML5's `data-*` attributes for storing custom data instead of defining your own standard-looking attributes.

  - I assume `trig` is short for "trigger", which is a runtime-defined event-name.

    - I've changed it to `data-event-name`.
    - You can get the value via `HTMLElement.dataset['eventName']`.

      - [`dataset` automatically converts `-` in HTML attribute names to `camelCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes), so you *don't* need to do `getAttribute("data-event-name").
  - I assume `loc` is short for "location", the `href` URI, basically. I've changed it to `data-href`.

Like so:

```js
function setupClickableEverything() {
    const allBodyElementsWithAttribs = document.querySelectorAll( 'body *[data-event-name][data-href]' );
    for( const el of allBodyElementsWithAttribs ) {
        const eventName = el.dataset['eventName'];
        el.addEventListener( eventName, setWindowLocationToDataSetHref );
    }
}

window.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', setupClickableEverything );

function setWindowLocationToDataSetHref( e ) {
    
    const el   = e.currentTarget;
    const href = el.dataset['href'];
    window.location = href;
}
```

Example HTML:

```
<b data-href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51390971/im-lost-what-happened-to-asp-net-mvc-5/51391202#51391202" data-event-name="click">Navigate on click</b>
<br />
<b data-href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15305278/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-a-specific-text/15305313#15305313" data-event-name="mousedown">Navigate on mousedown</b>
<br />
<b data-href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70011022/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-not-in-c/70011062#70011062" data-event-name="contextmenu">Navigate on right-click</b>
```

---

Here's a slightly modified demo using a StackOverflow snippet. <sub>Due to SO's CSP imposed on Snippets the demo below cannot navigate-away, open a popup, or load content into an `<iframe>`, but it still demonstrates it working *in principle*:</sub>

```js
function setupClickableEverything() {

    const allBodyElementsWithAttribs = document.querySelectorAll( 'body *[data-event-name][data-href]' );

    for( const el of allBodyElementsWithAttribs ) {
        
        const eventName = el.dataset['eventName'];
    //  const href      = el.dataset['href'];
        el.addEventListener( eventName, setWindowLocationToDataSetHref );
    }
}

window.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', setupClickableEverything );

function setWindowLocationToDataSetHref( e ) {
    
    const el   = e.currentTarget;
    const href = el.dataset['href'];
    //window.location = href;
    // To avoid breaking this demo, links are opened in the <iframe>.
    // StackOverflow snippets cannot use `window.open`.
    
//  document.getElementById('demoIFrame').src = href;
    document.getElementById('demoOutput').textContent = href;
}
```

```html
<b data-href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51390971/im-lost-what-happened-to-asp-net-mvc-5/51391202#51391202" data-event-name="click">Navigate on click</b>

<br />

<b data-href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15305278/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-a-specific-text/15305313#15305313" data-event-name="mousedown">Navigate on mousedown</b>

<br />

<b data-href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70011022/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-not-in-c/70011062#70011062" data-event-name="contextmenu">Navigate on right-click</b>

<hr />

<!-- To avoid breaking this demo, links are NOT actually opened, just shown in the <output> element below. I tried to make it work using an <iframe> but the CSP on SO prevents that. Note that SO snippets are blocked from using `window.open` too.  -->
<!--<iframe id="demoIFrame" width="500" height="500" border="1"></iframe>-->
<output id="demoOutput"></output>
```

Comment: Minor nitpick: Isn’t the “event name” more commonly called the event _type_?

Comment: @SebastianSimon You are technically correct ([the best kind of correct](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hou0lU8WMgo)) however in MDN's quasi-authoritative documentation they use the terms "name" and "type" interchangeably and given the OP seems new to JS and the DOM I wanted to use terms more easily-understood.

Comment: I am trying this but it doesn’t work. No errors, but the when I click on the text, nothing happens.

Comment: @JSst67 Did you use your debugger? Did you ensure the script only runs _after_ `DOMContentLoaded`?

Comment: @JSst67 I've updated my answer to contain a working example (albeit without actually navigating anywhere, due to security restrictions on SO snippets).

Comment: It works now, thanks! Just one question: if not to use on arrays then what is the purpose of `map` and `forEach`?